# TypeError: $ is undefined in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to use the "tabcordion" library in jquery on a Wordpress based website. The tabcordion javascript file is being 'enqueued' and appearing after the jquery file (so that bit looks ok).

The start of the jquery code is:

```
(function($) {
 var Tabcordion;

 $.fn.tabcordion = function(option) {
   return this.each(function() {
    var $this, data, options;
    $this = $(this);
    // rest of code ....
```

When I load my page I get the error "TypeError: $ is undefined" in Firebug

After a bit of googling I changed all the $. into jQuery.

That sorts some of the issues out but I then get an error about the line:

```
 $this = $(this);
```

I'm assuming that I don't have $ defined for jquery. I tried adding a line at the top of the function:

```
$ = jQuery;
```

but that didn't work.

Any ideas how I can get the $ to behave?

I have another script that works that is enclosed by:

```
(function($){ jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // code in here
}); })(jQuery);
```

But the end of tabcordion has:

```
(function($) {
  // tabcordion code....
}).call(this);
```

And the "call(this)" bit is throwing me?

Any ideas?

Comment: just change your $ to jQuery and it'll work if you have already loaded jquery

Comment: @AmitGarg: It's not the OP's code where the problem lies. It's tabcordian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to do anything to make `$` defined for jQuery other than include jQuery. The definition is part of the jQuery script.

This error tells you one of three things. Either:

1. You haven't included jQuery prior to including the plugin (or your attempt to has failed, e.g., a 404), or
2. You're loading something else after loading jQuery that is taking over the `$` symbol, or
3. You're calling `jQuery.noConflict()`, which releases the `$` symbol.

Based on your `$ = jQuery;` attempt not having worked, I'd say it's #1. So look to make sure the script tag is in the right place, and look to make sure you're not getting a 404 error (or similar) for it.

---

**Update** after your comment:

> I'm using a plugin called "use google libraries". That is calling jQuery.noConflict() after it has run.

First off, a Wordpress plugin calling `noConflict` seems like a bad idea to me. Similarly, tabcordian shouldn't be relying on the `$` symbol at all; jQuery plugins must not rely on `$` because people can use `noConflict`! And yet a quick look at the tabcordian source shows it doing exactly that: Relying on `$`.

I would recommend forking [tabcordian](https://github.com/aexmachina/tabcordion) and correcting it. The usual way you do that in a plugin is by opening with `(function($){` and ending with `})(jQuery);`, like this:

```
(function($) {
    // plugin code here, can use $ because it refers to our argument,
    // not the global symbol that may not be there
})(jQuery);
```

Re tabcordian's use of `.call(this)` that confused you:

```
(function() {
    // ...tabcordian source...
}).call(this);
```

That's utterly pointless if you're not using strict mode within the function, which tabcordian isn't. (If you *are* using strict mode, it's a way to make `this` continue to refer to the global object within the function.) But as that source is generated from CoffeeScript, this is probably boilerplate CoffeeScript stuff and it's probably doing that to support strict mode.

Comment: I'm using a plugin called "use google libraries". That is calling jQuery.noConflict() after it has run. Is there a way of 'undoing' this so that I redefine $ to be jQuery? I would rather not edit the plugin as any update will reintroduce the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnT: I've updated the answer to address your comment and the question at the end of your original question about `.call(this)`.

Comment: @TJ - thank you for your excellent reply. I've managed to get it working now. The clarification you provided has been a great help. I'm not familiar enough with Github in order to try and 'fork' something. I'd probably end up just forking it up ;-) so I'll leave that to someone with more experience. Thanks once again.