# How calling jquery method in CKEDITOR.dialog

Tags: jquery, color-picker

his there a way in CKEDITOR dialog plugin to call jquery function.
Basically, I would like to convert a Text element into a Jquery Color Picker

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'testtyni', function( editor ) {
     return {
        title: 'Edit Simple Box',
        minWidth: 200,
        minHeight: 100,
        contents: [
            {
                id: 'info',
                elements: [
                        {
                            type: 'text',
                            id: 'color',
                            label: 'Background Color',
                            'default': '',
                            setup:function(widget){
                                //$ Is Undefined
                                $(this).colorPicker();
                            }
                        }
                    ]
            }
        ]
    };
} );
```

The problem is that $ is not defined.

I guess I'll get a problem to call colorPicker method aswell.

Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're loading jQuery first? See this question for more information
[jQuery TypeError: $ is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475405/jquery-typeerror-is-undefined)