# Couchdb, jquery couch api

Tags: jquery, couchdb

I am using jquery couch api.

according to reference http://bradley-holt.com/2011/07/couchdb-jquery-plugin-reference/    CouchDB ships with several useful JavaScript libraries, including jQuery.

```
<script src="/_utils/script/json2.js"></script>
<script src="/_utils/script/sha1.js"></script>
<script src="/_utils/script/jquery.js?1.4.2"></script>
<script src="/_utils/script/jquery.couch.js?0.11.0"></script>
<script src="/_utils/script/jquery.dialog.js?0.11.0"></script>
```

Now I want to upgrade jquery to latest version.and don't want to use jquery which is ship with couchdb

So when I upgrade jquery to 1.11.2 , it shows "$ is undefined" error.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. fuhhh......

I was looking at wrong place. In fact jquery.couch.js is working with any version of jQuery library. So one can just add own jQuery library.

Problem which I facing is due to some other jQuery plugins.
So if any of you find this type of error "TypeError: $ is undefined" then please check whether you have included jQuery and all plugins in proper sequence.also check if you are required to use $.noconflict() or not.

also refer below link
[TypeError: $ is undefined in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660326/typeerror-is-undefined-in-jquery)

Thanks,
Nirmal